# Call Python Code inside C++ Class to manipulate an Object

Tags: python, c++, embed

I am currently using pybind11 to embed python into my program.
I call the update() function in which I want to run python code on all objects (hundreds of objects) created from a certain class. The problem is, that I need to hand over a pointer to the object(`this`) that is calling the python code to python.

So basically I have a class like that (minimal pseudo C++ Code):

```
class A
{
public:
    A(Data* d)
    {
        dat = d;
        createPyObject(passToPython);
    }

    void update()
    {
        launchPythonCode(passToPython);
    }

    Data* getData(){return dat;}
    static void createPythonClassDef()
    {
        pybind11::class_<A>(module, "A")
        .def("getData",&A::getData);
    }

private:

    void createPyObject(PyObject* p)
    {
        //HowTo?
    }

    Data* dat;
    PyObject* passToPython;
};
```

What I tried:
Adding a function returning the pointer to the class and creating a Python localdictionary containing a function getA() that would point to that function. So each Object would contain their own localdictionary with the getA() function returning its pointer.
That should give Python the object but it didn't work.

I hope someone can tell me how to correctly embed python for that purpose.